# ios 8 How to make Fullscreen at launch?

Tags: xcode, ios8, fullscreen

I found this, when working on my app:

http://imgur.com/I0ciVTw&iZYUhWv#0 <- happens on launch

http://imgur.com/I0ciVTw&iZYUhWv#1 <- happens just a few sec after launch

My Question is: How to make the app launch like on pic2?

Edit1: 
added Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    // load the content controller object for Phone-based devices
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Content_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];

}
else
{
    // load the content controller object for Pad-based devices
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Content_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
        self.window.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
    }

}


self.window.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   // Add registration for remote notifications
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

[[ProvisioningHandler sharedHandler] startHandling];

TLNAdManager *manager = [TLNAdManager sharedManager];
manager.advertisementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:AdvertisementURLString];
manager.rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
[manager update];

return YES;
}
```

Thanks!

I fixed it:
Turned window hidden and it works.

Comment: is it working identical when you run simulator or device? Did you try cleaning the project? It does not have any sense if you do not have some type of code to change UI if it is changing without intervention.

Comment: Device and Simulator the same, cleaning project and reset simulator  has the same result

Comment: no ideas? i created the views via nib´s